Android WebView saveState and restroreState are not working properly
private var savedStateMap = ConcurrentHashMap<String, Bundle>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    loadUrl("some url")
}

private fun loadUrl(urltoLoad: String) {
    Log.d(WEBVIEW_TAG, "${mBinding.webView}")

    mBinding.webView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaInterface, "webkit")

    mBinding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView, url: String, favicon: Bitmap?) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
            mBinding.loading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url)
            mBinding.loading.visibility = View.GONE
        }

        override fun onReceivedHttpError(
            view: WebView?,
            request: WebResourceRequest?,
            errorResponse: WebResourceResponse?,
        ) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse)
            Log.d(WEBVIEW_TAG, "Error Loading due to ${errorResponse?.reasonPhrase}")
        }
    }

    mBinding.webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)

            if (newProgress == 100) {
                val newUrl = view?.url
                if (newUrl == lastVisitedUrl) {
                    //Same page don't to anything....
                } else {
                    //url is changed now here...
                    newUrl?.let {
                        Log.d(WEBVIEW_TAG, "Url is changing::$it")
                        lastVisitedUrl = it
                        val currentState = Bundle()
                        mBinding.webView.saveState(currentState)
                        savedStateMap[appUrl.toString()] = currentState
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for ((url, state) in savedStateMap) {
        Log.d(WEBVIEW_TAG, "MyMap:::URL: $url, State: $state")
    }

    //Check if the URL has been visited before
    val isPresent = savedStateMap.containsKey(appUrl)

    if (isPresent) {
        val previousState = savedStateMap[appUrl]
        if (previousState != null) {
            mBinding.webView.restoreState(previousState)
            Log.d(WEBVIEW_TAG, "Already Loaded $previousState")
        } else {
            Log.d(WEBVIEW_TAG, "state is not captured properly")
            mBinding.webView.loadUrl(appUrl!!)
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(WEBVIEW_TAG, "New to Load")
        mBinding.webView.loadUrl(appUrl!!)
    }
}

I am loading multiple url into my single webview one by one using his loadUrl() method and it is taking url to load in my webview for the first time but also I want to store the last state or last visited endpoint of that url so that if any url comes that is alreday been loaded then it should redirect or restate the previous state if not then load the url again.
Is this the correct way to do this? If not then what is the correct way to do this?
